# How to move data from one table to another in Postgres (while working with PK's)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm optimizing my current database with new and better tables. I'm trying to move the data over without having to worry about the integrity of my primary key's. I've been trying multiple methods but I keep getting duplicate error's / or postgres expecting an int type for primary key's when I'm not trying to insert or move data into a PK column. Just to clarify, the new tables I made are completely empty and are waiting for data.

For example, I want to move the data from `Table1` =

```
CREATE TABLE public.security_recs
(
    idx integer,
    symbol character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    rating_buy numeric,
    rating_overweight numeric,
    rating_hold numeric,
    rating_underweight numeric,
    rating_sell numeric,
    rating_none numeric,
    rating_scale numeric,
    consensus_start_date date NOT NULL,
    consensus_end_date date,
    corp_actions_applied date,
    total_recs integer,
    pull_date date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT security_recs_pkey PRIMARY KEY (symbol, consensus_start_date, pull_date)
)
```

to the NEW `Table1` =

```
CREATE TABLE public.security_recs_test
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    symbol character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    rating_buy numeric,
    rating_overweight numeric,
    rating_hold numeric,
    rating_underweight numeric,
    rating_sell numeric,
    rating_none numeric,
    rating_scale numeric,
    consensus_start_date date NOT NULL,
    consensus_end_date date,
    corp_actions_applied date,
    total_recs integer,
    pull_date date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT security_recs_test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, consensus_start_date, pull_date),
    CONSTRAINT security_recs_test_symbol_fkey FOREIGN KEY (symbol)
        REFERENCES public.security_test (symbol) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Both have 14 columns, I only want to copy 13 columns (minus `idx`), and let the NEW and improved table auto increment for the remaining column (being a PK).

I thought this simple query could help solve for my pains

```
INSERT INTO security_recs_test
SELECT (symbol, rating_buy, rating_overweight, rating_hold, rating_underweight,  
                    rating_sell, rating_none, rating_scale, consensus_start_date, consensus_end_date,
                    corp_actions_applied, total_recs)
FROM security_recs;
```

but I got this error as it's expecting an int in place for the PK column (I thought putting the columns I want in a list would solve for this):

```
Error: column "id" is of type bigint but expression is of type record
LINE 5: SELECT (symbol, rating_buy, rating_overweight, rating_hold, ...
               ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

no luck, I've tried other similar ones but not sure if I'm going in the right direction...

Stuck in the mud here and would love some help on how to move forward with my case.

EDIT:

I'm trying now this this query, as recommended by the comments, still trying to figure out the correct sytanx.

```
INSERT INTO (symbol, rating_buy, rating_overweight, rating_hold, rating_underweight,  
                    rating_sell, rating_none, rating_scale, consensus_start_date, consensus_end_date,
                    corp_actions_applied, total_recs security_recs_test)
SELECT symbol, rating_buy, rating_overweight, rating_hold, rating_underweight,  
                    rating_sell, rating_none, rating_scale, consensus_start_date, consensus_end_date,
                    corp_actions_applied, total_recs
FROM security_recs;
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses around the column list

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Sadly this does not work and I still get the same error. See Gordon's comment for my response.

Comment: You are going to have to include  the column list in the `INSERT` portion and as others have said lose the parentheses in the `SELECT` portion. Otherwise the `SELECT` fields will be assigned left to right to the table columns. Also I don't see `pull_date` in `SELECT` and it is `NOT NULL` in the table.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, thank you for catching the missing column from my statement. I am following your advice and the advice of others. I updated my post with a new query that I'm using but need a little but help on the syntax.

Comment: `INSERT INTO security_recs_test(symbol, ...)` It is all spelled out here [Insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html). The docs are there for just this question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you sir for the help and the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query returns one column, a tuple, that has multiple fields:

```
SELECT (symbol, rating_buy, rating_overweight, rating_hold, rating_underweight,  
                    rating_sell, rating_none, rating_scale, consensus_start_date, consensus_end_date,
                    corp_actions_applied, total_recs)
FROM security_recs;
```

This query -- without the parentheses -- returns multiple columns:

```
SELECT symbol, rating_buy, rating_overweight, rating_hold, rating_underweight,  
                    rating_sell, rating_none, rating_scale, consensus_start_date, consensus_end_date,
                    corp_actions_applied, total_recs
FROM security_recs;
```

As a best practice, I would recommend that you list all the columns for the `insert` as well:

```
INSERT INTO security_recs_test (symbol, rating_buy, rating_overweight, rating_hold, rating_underweight,  
                    rating_sell, rating_none, rating_scale, consensus_start_date, consensus_end_date,
                    corp_actions_applied, total_recs)
    SELECT symbol, rating_buy, rating_overweight, rating_hold, rating_underweight,  
           rating_sell, rating_none, rating_scale, consensus_start_date, consensus_end_date,
           corp_actions_applied, total_recs
    FROM security_recs;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Removing the parentheses still callsback the same error I linked above. The table is expecting an int in place before thr `symbol` column.

Comment: @Dre . . . Follow the advice and list the columns being inserted as part of the `insert` statement.

Comment: can you kindly check my edit in the OG post for some guidance on the correct syntax for this? Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you so much! Managed to fix my issue.